# Zedgraph realtime x axis formatting to prevent "label jumps"

Tags: c#, real-time, zedgraph

I have been working with zedgraph and I am having trouble with how the data is scrolling on the X axis for real time data.

I have stripped my code down to a simple example taken from 
[Zedgraph Realtime Example](http://zedgraph.dariowiz.com/index3061.html?title=Display_Dynamic_or_Real-Time_Data) slightly modified mainly changing the display time to 10 seconds and formatting the X axis as a date.

```
double displaySeconds = 10;
```

When I change the display time to any value more than 8 seconds, something strange happens.  The Labels on the X axis scroll but will always "jump" to the newest second value rather than the labels following the points on the graph.  If I set the display seconds to 5 everythings works as I want.

```
double displaySeconds = 5;
```

Can anyone please help me with making these labels stick to the points on the graphs.

Code is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZedGraph;

namespace ZedGraphSample
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int tickStart = 0;
        Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        double displaySeconds = 10;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
            RollingPointPairList list = new RollingPointPairList(1200);
            LineItem curve = myPane.AddCurve("Voltage", list, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None);

            timer1.Interval = 50;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Start();

            int numberOfDivisions = 4;
            myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorStep = (int)displaySeconds / numberOfDivisions;
            myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep = (int)displaySeconds / numberOfDivisions;
            myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
            myPane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
            //myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStepAuto = false;
            //myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorStepAuto = false;
            myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorUnit = DateUnit.Second;
            myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorUnit = DateUnit.Second;

            zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
            tickStart = Environment.TickCount;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LineItem curve = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList[0] as LineItem;
            IPointListEdit list = curve.Points as IPointListEdit;
            double time = (Environment.TickCount - tickStart) / 1000.0;

            list.Add(DateTime.Now.ToOADate(), Math.Sin(2.0 * Math.PI * time / 3.0));

            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = now.ToOADate();
            zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-displaySeconds).ToOADate();

            zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
            zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
        }

    }
}
```